# Make this code pylint correct

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def scanDevices(self):
    """ Start 2 threads, one for scanning devices and other for displaying device list on UI
    """
    self.counter = self.counter + 1
    deviceListChangedEvent = threading.Event()
    threadToScanDevices = threading.Thread(target=test_ssdp.main, args=(self.getHostIP(), self.counter, deviceListChangedEvent,))
    threadToScanDevices.setDaemon(True)
    threadToScanDevices.start()
    threadToDisplayDevices = threading.Thread(target=self.displayDevices, args=(deviceListChangedEvent,))
    threadToDisplayDevices.setDaemon(True)
    threadToDisplayDevices.start()
    self.scan.setEnabled(False)
    self.cw.btnPushProfile.setEnabled(False)
```

How to make this code pylint correct ?

error - line too long

Comment: Please, paste the entire error

Comment: after `self.getHostIP(),` take the rest of the line onto the next line (hit enter). It it still contained in the `()`'s so python will treat it as a single line of code.

Comment: @CasualDemon what about indentation of that next line ? can u please write the code

Comment: Check out the other's answers below, both should solve it for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the line shorter by splitting it over multiple lines, using Python's implicit line continuation inside parentheses/brackets/braces:

```
threadToScanDevices = threading.Thread(target=test_ssdp.main, 
                                       args=(self.getHostIP(), 
                                             self.counter, 
                                             deviceListChangedEvent,))
```

(Note the use of alignment to make it clear which sub-lines belong together).

Alternatively, split the line into more than one statement:

```
args = self.getHostIP(), self.counter, deviceListChangedEvent
threadToScanDevices = threading.Thread(target=test_ssdp.main, args=args)
```

You should limit to 79 characters per [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> **Maximum line length**
>
> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.
>
> For flowing long blocks of text with fewer structural restrictions (docstrings or comments), the line length should be limited to 72 characters.
>
> Limiting the required editor window width makes it possible to have several files open side-by-side, and works well when using code review tools that present the two versions in adjacent columns.

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix a "line too long" error is - make the line shorter!

```
def scanDevices(self):
    """ Start 2 threads, one for scanning devices and other
        for displaying device list on UI
    """
    self.counter = self.counter + 1
    deviceListChangedEvent = threading.Event()
    threadToScanDevices = threading.Thread(target=test_ssdp.main,
                                           args=(self.getHostIP(),
                                           self.counter,
                                           deviceListChangedEvent,))
    # etc
```

Because the line is broken inside parentheses, Python knows that the statement is continued on the next line.